# What does `se` stand for in geom_smooth(..., se = FALSE)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

From documentation:

> **se**  Display confidence interval around smooth (TRUE by default, see level to control.)

Source: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_smooth.html

So where did "s" and "e" come from???

Comment: See under [Computed Variables](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_smooth.html#computed-variables): "standard error"

Comment: **s**tandard **e**rror of the prediction? See for instance `predict` with se.fit parameter

Comment: What does standard error have to do with confidence intervals?

Comment: @noname almost everything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is admittedly a slightly oblique name, but as @Guillaume says, it refers to the standard error of the estimated response. Internally, `ggplot` is typically calling the `predict()` method of the smoothed object with `se.fit = TRUE`; e.g. you can see the code [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/65662cf4cd38d2cfd883198dc1a594ea093e98b9/R/stat-smooth-methods.r#L26-L42). It then computes the confidence interval based on a set number of standard-error intervals around the predicted value (for the typical 95% CI, this is `predicted ± 1.96 * se`).

The *Details* section of `geom_smooth` says:

> Calculation is performed by the (currently undocumented)
> ‘predictdf()’ generic and its methods.  For most methods the
> standard error bounds are computed using the ‘predict()’ method -
> the exceptions are ‘loess()’, which uses a t-based approximation,
> and ‘glm()’, where the normal confidence interval is constructed
> on the link scale and then back-transformed to the response scale.

Comment: Calling it the "std error of the prediction" seems very problematic. It is generally called the "std error of the estimate" since it is trying to define a range of most plausible values for the mean of the y-variable. You can have "prediction intervals" but they are much wider since the goal is to capture a band that will contain some large fraction, typically 19 out of 20 (95%) of the values rather than trying to capture a much smaller band of plausible means.

Answer (score 0):

In the statistical context, this shorthand means 'standard error', but what it actually means (and *does*) here in this ggplot2 function is to compute the *(95%) **confidence intervals*** of estimates (as it says in the instruction for the parameter `se`). This said, it's a bit confusing. The name of this parameter in the function could have been revised to something like '*ci*' for clarity, but this is yet to happen :D